# Using _id collection Meteor as an integer

Tags: javascript, meteor

Ok I been researching a lot about trying to use an auto increment int in the `_id` field instead of a `string`, by now Im using `mrt:mongo-counter` for auto increment and `peerlibrary:directcollection` for access directly to mongoDB. I have an Meteor collection name venue as

```
Venues = new Mongo.Collection("venues");
```

And I have tried all different way of use the int in the `_id` field and as I know Meteor dont allow other than `string` or `ObjectId` as identifiers, is any way for a work around for this?

this is my code:

```
function makeNewId(){
   return incrementCounter("venueId",1);
}

var venueDirect = new DirectCollection(Venues, makeNewId);

var _venueId = venueDirect.insert(
    {
        userId : _userId,
        created : new Date(),
        name : "",
        description : "",
        cover : "",
        image : "",
        location : "",
        suspended : false,
        visible : false
    }
);
```

I also tried with:

```
    var _venueId = Venue.insert(
        {
            _id : incrementCounter("venueId",1),
            userId : _userId,
            created : new Date(),
            name : "",
            description : "",
            cover : "",
            image : "",
            location : "",
            suspended : false,
            visible : false
        }
    );
```

without result.

How can I find a workaround for work with `int` as `_id` in meteor

Comment: Yes, why not just add a new field, `incrementingId` or something, that has the properties you want, and keep the existing `_id`?

Comment: @stubailo Look like is a requirement on mongodb for some reason -sight-. But I cant find a way to do it.

Comment: @BrendanTurner The purpose is cause we have a python backend service which need receive the _id as int.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended doing it is storing the `id` number as `string` format, so now you will have a sequence as `"1"` `"2"` etc... not the best solution but is one I found that make most of the developers in my project happy -sigh-

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to dig through. Seems like most of meteor user base is not inclined to use integer ids. Some even suggested to keep the integer id in a separate field. I didn't really have a choice, since I had an existing DB with int ids.

Anyways, finally **rawCollection** came to my rescue.

```
Venues = new Mongo.Collection("venues");
VenuesRawCollection = Venues.rawCollection();

VenuesRawCollection.insert(
    {
        _id : Venues.findOne({}, {sort: {_id: -1}})._id + 1,
        userId : _userId,
        created : new Date(),
        name : "",
        description : "",
        cover : "",
        image : "",
        location : "",
        suspended : false,
        visible : false
    }
);
```

Note: Fair warning. By using rawCollection, you will loose any of autoValue magic from SimpleSchema/collections2.

Comment: you could run into a race condition with this approach two or three user being created it at the same. this is not an atomic insert right?

Comment: yes. but you can modify it to use a value derived from a mongo counter and use it's value as the id. that will resolve the race condition as well.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/